# How to create a dictionary with columns given as keys and values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key, key-value

Ok so I am given two columns

```
A S

A T

A Z

B F

B G

B P

B U

C D

C P

C R

D M

E H

F S

H U
```

The 1st column is a list of points, and the second column is the list of the neighbors of the points. I would like to make it a dictionary so that
{A:'S','T','Z', B:'F','G','P' etc} and so on.

What I have tried doing is this, given that the text file is the two columns.

```
edges = open('romEdges.txt')

edgeslist = edges.read().split()

edgeskeys = edgeslist[::2]

edgesvalues = edgeslist[1::2]


dictionary = {}

for items in edgeskeys:

    dictionary[items]=[]

dictionary = OrderedDict(sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))

for items in edgeskeys:

    if edgeskeys[items]==dictionary[items]:

        print()

print(dictionary)
```

I have tried making 2 lists, 1 of keys and 1 of values, and tried comparing them to the dictionary, etc, and I just can't get it right!

THERE HAS to be a simple way.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For People who just want to create a simple dictionary from colums without recurring keyvalues this should work:

```
 edges = open('romEdges.txt')
 dict = {line[:1]:line[1:] for line in edges}
 print dict
 edges.close()
```

now you have possibly some whitespaces or Backspaces in the values, then you can replace() that with empty strings:

```
 edges = open('romEdges.txt')
 dict = {line[:1]:line[1:].split()[0] for line in edges}
 print dict
 edges.close()
```

if you have multiple colums, and you want to have a list out of the following colums to that keyvalue:

```
 edges = open('romEdges.txt')
 dict = {line[:1]:line[1:].split() for line in edges}
 print dict
 edges.close()
```

Comment: I tried running this but all the keys only had one value, whereas some of them are supposed to have multiple values. Thanks for your effort though.

Comment: So do you know how to do it the 'correct' way? edit: other user helped.
thanks anyways!

Comment: no problem, for your next problem look at my 3rd answer without the[0]. The Problem with my solution was, that you had to append the list, that you can't do in the oneline dict generator as far as. i know

Comment: i generalized my answer for people that come here to search for this problem in general

Comment: so you mean about the problem with 3 columns that I commented on the other answer? edit: wow thank! It worked!

Comment: Thanks buddy, I wish I could give both of you guys best answer as you really helped a lot man. Unfortunately he was able to help me with the original answer, but you helped me with an equally important problem. Thanks! I'll just give u best answer since u have lower rep than him :p

Answer (score 2):

Why not just plain simple line-by-line processing?

```
f = open('romEdges.txt')
dic = {}
for l in f:
    k, v = l.split()
    if k in dic:
        dic[k].extend(v)
    else:
        dic[k] = [v]
f.close()
print dic
```

Output from your input:

```
{'A': ['S', 'T', 'Z'], 'C': ['D', 'P', 'R'], 'B': ['F', 'G', 'P', 'U'], 'E': ['H'], 'D': ['M'], 'F': ['S'], 'H': ['U']}
```

Comment: 'dict' has no attribute 'has_key'

Comment: In that case, use `k in dic` instead of `dic.has_key(k)`.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out right now. Thanks for your help. Your answer works!

Comment: How would you do a similar thing, if you were given 3 columns, the 2nd and 3rd column being the values for the 1st column, except this time the 1st column does not have anything repeating?

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open('romEdges.txt')

dic = {}
```

for **l** in **f**:

```
k, v = l.split('\t')
dic.setdefault(k,[])
if k in dic.keys():
    dic[k].extend([v.strip()])
else:
    dic[k] =[v]
f.close()

print dic
```