# how to load raw data in a text file in to pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, loaddata

My data is in a text file in the format shown below:

**heading1**:blah

**heading2**:blah

**heading3**:blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah (**text entered new line for heading3 only for this row**)

---

**heading1**:blah

**heading2**:blah

**heading3**:blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah

so on...

**Note**:

- heading3 data going to the next line.
- here is the Zip file [link](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/wiki-RfA.html) for the dataset

Comment: heading 3 data can go in to next line

Comment: Need a better picture of what the input data looks like, unless you're literally loading a text file with a bunch of "blah" strings. e.g. can you use the string `split` method on the values to turn them into lists?

Comment: Hi, the data is [here](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/wiki-RfA.html) in a zip file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for posting the link to the data. If it's publicly available, it's helpful to do that initially. I ran this on the full data set; that took a couple of seconds on a decent laptop.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

with open('rfa_all.NL-SEPARATED.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

# create a dictionary with keys and lists.
# if you don't set the values as lists, you get an error.
d = {'SRC': [], 'TGT': [], 'VOT': [],  'RES': [],  'YEA': [],  'DAT': [],  'TXT': []}

for line in data: # go through file line by line
    if line != '\n': # skip new line characters
        line = line.replace('\n', '') # get rid of '\n' in all fields
        key, val = line.split(':', 1) # take the first 2 tokens from the split statement
        d[key].append(val)

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df
```

Extensive help from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26644245/6672746

I am sure there is a much faster way to set this up, but I think this will work.

Comment: The formatting in the actual file is sufficiently different than in your example, so it breaks the split(':') statement. I'll try to take another look later.